# Holding down delete key in macOS Sierra doesn't keep deleting

Tags: keyboard, macos

Under El Capitan, if I try to delete a line of text (like this sentence) by holding down the delete key on my Logitech K750, it keeps deleting until I release the key.

Under Sierra, I have to hit the delete key repeatedly until I get to the end of the sentence.

How can I restore this functionality to what it should be?

Comment: It works just fine and as it should with an Apple keyboard. Have you updated the [Logitech Control Center for Macintosh® OS X](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/logitech-control-center-for-macintosh-os-x) for macOS Sierra?  If not, give it a try.

Comment: Installing the control center fixed the problem. Thanks.